# How can we prove that the group order is an upper bound both for the number and the dimensionalities of the irreducible representations?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

For example, in $S_{3}$ there is 6 number of members for the group while there are 3 different irreducible representation with dimensinalities of 1, 1 and 2 in which gives:
$$\sum_{\mu}{n_{\mu}^2} = 1^{2} + 1^{2} + 2^{2} = 6$$ 
and generally,
$$\sum_{\mu}{n_{\mu}^2} \le g$$

Comment: There is no such word as dimensionality. The usual word for this is "degree".

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if $W_1,\cdots,W_h$ are irreducible representations of $G$ and $h$ is the number of conjugacy classes of $G$ (which equals the number of irreducible representations), letting $n_i \overset{def}= \dim W_i$, then one has 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^h n_i^2 = g.
$$
The proof is somewhat lengthy and involves proving many little intermediate results ; I suggest you take the time to read up in a reference. I suggest to you Serre's "Linear representations of finite groups", as Serre is by far one of the best writers out there (if not the best, in my opinion). I did read it up to Chapter III (did not read Chapter III, since it is quite advanced in comparison with the rest) and it was an incredible high-quality read. Read it from page 1, skip the proofs of the results you know and get to that result, this is probably your best shot.

Hope that helps,